# What is the difference between autossh and ssh that is put in a while loop?

Tags: shell-script, ssh

From this [website](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) it says that:

> Autossh is a program to start a copy of ssh and monitor it, restarting
>   it as necessary should it die or stop passing traffic.

But I really can't see the difference between autossh and an ssh tunnel that is inside `while loop`. I personally use this ssh tunnel script to restart the tunnel when it gets disconnected:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    ssh -vND 1080 username@host
    sleep 1
done
```

So what is the difference between these two ? I would love to use autossh if it has more benefits than an ssh that is inside a `while loop` function

Comment: Did you try downloading the source code and reading through it?

Comment: I've read the `README` file but English isn't my first language and I'm not a tech savvy, I'm struggling hard to understand the differences between these two, can you please explain the differences in a simple way?

Comment: I don't know the difference myself.  *If* the program is very well written, it might be more effective or more flexible than your shell loop.  From the README it looks like one key difference would be that `autossh` wouldn't restart an ssh session if it was exited normally.

Answer (score 0):

Main difference is that `autossh` has many options in it, as can be read in it man page.

For example:

```
-f      causes autossh to drop to the background before running ssh. The -f flag is stripped from arguments passed to ssh. Note that there is a crucial a difference between -f with autossh, and -f with ssh: when used with autossh ssh will be unable to ask for passwords or passphrases. When -f is used, the "starting gate" time (see AUTOSSH_GATETIME) is set to 0.
```